# Randomize the order of some links

Tags: jquery, html, random

I have a code like this (static):

```
<a href="#">link 1</a>
<a href="#">link 2</a>
<a href="#">link 3</a>
```

I would like to know if it is possible to read these `<a>` tags and randomize their order with JQuery, so that it will (for instance) show:

```
<a href="#">link 1</a>
<a href="#">link 3</a>
<a href="#">link 2</a>
```

Comment: What is the source for the links?  If using a DB then why not return them in random order.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Randomize a sequence of div elements with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533910/randomize-a-sequence-of-div-elements-with-jquery)

Comment: I'm nothing using DB (it's statis), the source don't matter in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var elems = $('a');
elems.sort(function() { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); });  
for(var i=0; i < elems.length; i++) elems.parent().append(elems[i]);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MQqM3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This will return the links in random order.

```
$("a").sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()})
```

So I guess if you put the links in a container you can then repopulate it with the reordered array.

Comment: I found this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9641564/1102592 . I'll try this too @nico

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your mysql query in the first place using ORDER BY RAND() or using JQUERY
you can assign id to each a tags and append it randomly to its parent element using the this plugin: [Random - jQuery plugin](http://www.rockechris.com/jquery/jquery.random.js.html)

Comment: I think his page is static, otherwise `ORDER BY RAND()` would be a good option when pulling links from a DB.

Answer (score 0):

All those sound good, but you could make a simple plugin in like so:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        randomize: function() {
            return $.randomize($(this).get());
        }
    });
    $.randomize = function(arr) {
        for(var j, x, i = arr.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x);
        return $(arr);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And then use it as such:

```
$("#someEleID").prepend($("a").randomize());
```

or:

```
$("#someEleID").prepend($.randomize($("a")));
```