# Random Div Order on Page Load

Tags: html

I have a bunch of divs with the ID "gallerycard". I need them to load in a random order every time the user visits the page.

```
<div id="gallerycard">
     <div id="name">Akulina</div>
    <div id="info">N/A</div>
</div>

<div id="gallerycard">
     <div id="name">Martina</div>
    <div id="info">N/A</div>
</div>

<div id="gallerycard">
     <div id="name">Joseph</div>
    <div id="info">N/A</div>
</div>

<div id="gallerycard">
     <div id="name">Karen</div>
    <div id="info">N/A</div>
</div>
...
```

And...

**Here's the fiddle with CSS:** http://jsfiddle.net/BwJHj/

I know this is a simple task for most of you but I really struggle with jquery at times :(

**Thank you**

Comment: Show us what you have done so far...-the attempts you have done for this...

Comment: Its invalid to use same id for multiple divs.use class instead of id.

Comment: Can anyone edit this to enable syntax highlighting ?

Comment: @VaibhavJain *not good practice*? Its **invalid**

Comment: Id is always unique, use class instead if you want to use the same for all

Comment: I tried to use the instructions from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315177/any-way-to-shuffle-content-in-multiple-div-elements

Comment: Ids always need to be unique.You are assigning the same id to different divs. If you need to select the different divs using a selector, assign them the same class not the same id.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**HTML**

First change all of the `id`s to `classes` since `id` must be unique on a page.

```
<div class="gallerycard">
     <div class="name">Akulina</div>
    <div class="info">N/A</div>
</div>

<div class="gallerycard">
     <div class="name">Martina</div>
    <div class="info">N/A</div>
</div>

<div class="gallerycard">
     <div class="name">Joseph</div>
    <div class="info">N/A</div>
</div>
...
```

**CSS** (Since markup now uses classes switch the style to reflect)

```
.gallerycard {
    margin: 8px;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    width: 221px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

**Javascript**

Select all card elements from the DOM then generate two randoms between 0 and cards.length.  Use `eq` to select a random element in the selected elements and position it before another randomly selected element in the set of selected eleemnts.

```
var cards = $(".gallerycard");
for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
    var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length -1) + 1;
    var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length -1) +1;
    cards.eq(target).before(cards.eq(target2));
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/BwJHj/1/

Comment: Wow, that's actually a pretty weird way to shuffle: you change order of a randomly taken element `length` times instead of just giving each `i`-th element a new random position. If it stays this way, only in best case scenario all elements will be shuffled, but most times there will be _gaps_ of elements that stayed on the original place.