# Randomized Divs each time a page is reloaded/refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw this post:
[Random Div Order on Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483241/random-div-order-on-page-load)

and the working solution was posted:
jsfiddle.net/BwJHj/1/

Which works each time I refresh that page ^ As soon as I make my own, or even just copy the exact HTML/CSS/JAVA from that demo, it doesn't work?

Just wondering why that may be.

Answer (score 0):

Select Javascript from settings and it will work

```
   without javascript : [https://jsfiddle.net/UserIsMonica/daw5nytd/][1] (no randomize)

  with Javascript : [https://jsfiddle.net/UserIsMonica/daw5nytd/1/][2] (Randomize)
```

[image]

It's common first time Jsfiddle user can easily miss that. i did :) 
happy coding !!