# Randomize flex box order

Tags: html, css, angularjs, flexbox

This may seem a little odd, but I need to randomize the order of 4 flexbox items. These need to be randomized onInit.

I could randomize the numbers in javascript, but how do I bind that property to CSS?

This is my code:

CSS:

```
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 2rem;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="buttons">
    <button>{{ mcqs.answer1 }}</button>
    <button>{{ mcqs.answer2 }}</button>
    <button>{{ mcqs.answer3 }}</button>
    <button>{{ mcqs.answer4 }}</button>
  </div>
```

Basically I just need a really simple way to randomize the order of the answers (for a multiple choice test application). Thanks!

Comment: I think you can repeat your buttons like this: `<button ng-repeat="(key,value) in mcqs">{{value}}</button>`. Then you can consider adding some dynamic class with `ng-class="get_random_class($index)"`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to conditionally apply classes to your elements using a function in your AngularJS controller. Add CSS rules for those classes.

```
<style>
.col-order-1 {
    order: 1;
}
.col-order-2 {
    order: 2;
}
</style>

<div class="buttons" ng-class="getOrderClass($index)"> ... </div>
```

Don't try to modify the CSS directly. You could also build the entire button list markup in the controller and bind that instead.

Comment: The $index parameter would require me to loop the buttons in ng-repeat, correct? I will only ever have 4 buttons, so is it possible to randomize which class it collects from the function, based on a parameter of (lets say) 1,2,3 or 4? This i just my initial idea at least, I don't need to loop the buttons.

Comment: Yep. I didn't indicate a repeat, but that might be the simplest approach. Simplifying your markup is nice, and you already have the array (or can easily create one).

Comment: Adding a class won't change the order that flexbox displays content. It's always going to display content in the order of the markup UNLESS you specify `flex-order`

Comment: @BryceHowitson, [order can be applied via CSS classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items), no?

Comment: @isherwood the link you referenced doesn't allow random order it's based on markup order and can only define if the presentation starts with the first or the last item.

Comment: Of course it doesn't refer to randomizing--that's done in the JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point, though. [Here's more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) on specifying order in class rules.

Comment: @isherwood, my point is that the OP specifically asked about randomizing the order of flexbox display in CSS

Comment: Yep, and not only is that practically infeasible, it's not a good practice in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

try this, you wont need to randomize numbers :

```js
var answers  = $("button");
for(var i = 0; i < answers .length; i++){
    var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers .length -1) + 1;
    var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers .length -1) +1;
    answers .eq(target).before(answers .eq(target2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
    <button>{{ mcqs.answer1 }}</button>
    <button>{{ mcqs.answer2 }}</button>
    <button>{{ mcqs.answer3 }}</button>
    <button>{{ mcqs.answer4 }}</button>
  </div>
```

original answer here : 
[Random Div Order on Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483241/random-div-order-on-page-load)

Comment: Ack! jQuery in and AngularJS project? I say again... ack!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `flex-order` to the `buttons` to force them to display in any order independent of the markup.

Here's the basic use case:

```
.flex-item {
   order: 1;
}
```

Or you can add the CSS inline like so:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button ng-style="{'order': randomIndexNum}">{{ mcqs.answer1 }</button>
    <button ng-style="{'order': randomIndexNum}">{{ mcqs.answer2 }</button>
    <button ng-style="{'order': randomIndexNum}">{{ mcqs.answer3 }</button>
    <button ng-style="{'order': randomIndexNum}">{{ mcqs.answer4 }</button>
</div>
```

This can be done with Angular or any other tools that can modify the HTML onInit.

Documentation from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/)

Comment: How does this allow one to randomize the order?

Comment: You can put any integer in that item to force the order it displays in a flex-box based layout instead of the order it appears in markup.

Answer (score 0):

I would get the buttons container, convert it to an array, shuffle the images and populate it again with the result

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    buttons {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      /* Initially hide the container */
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    button {
      /* Add your button styles here */
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      /* Add any other styles as needed */
    }
  </style>
  <title>Randomize Buttons</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="buttons">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <!-- Add more buttons as needed -->
</div>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    // Get the container and the buttons
    var container = document.querySelector(".buttons");
    var buttons = container.querySelectorAll("button");

    // Convert NodeList to an array for easy manipulation
    var buttonsArray = Array.from(buttons);

    // Shuffle the array (randomize the order)
    buttonsArray.sort(function() {
      return 0.5 - Math.random();
    });

    // Clear the container and append the shuffled buttons
    container.innerHTML = "";
    buttonsArray.forEach(function(button) {
      container.appendChild(button);
    });

    // Show the container after rearranging the buttons
    container.style.visibility = "visible";
  };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```