# Randomize the order of divs in a flexbox

Tags: html, css, random, flexbox

I have a site that displays many creator in a flexbox (wich happens to be in a grid), and i was wondering how could i make the site shuffle the divs in a way that everytime the page is loaded i get a random sort.
This is the simplified code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="creators-wrapper">
   <div class="creator">John</div>
   <div class="creator">Michael</div>
   <div class="creator">David</div>
   <div class="creator">Kevin</div>
   <div class="creator">Sarah</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.creators-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.creator {
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Now, can i randomize the order of the creators' divs?

Comment: i think this question solves your question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483241/random-div-order-on-page-load). you also need javascript code

Comment: @user12632699 yeah i saw that before asking my question, but i really couldn't understand it, i tried to apply his solution to my code but i couldn't make it work

Comment: okay. i will take a solution for you.... give me a minute

Comment: hear is the solution --> [https://jsfiddle.net/swisscodemen/qf5kznwu/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/swisscodemen/qf5kznwu/1/)

Comment: You can use flexbox order, i dont think is duplicated

Comment: I'm not sure it's a duplicate either, anyway the solution worked, i spent a little time understanding jquery (i'm a beginner as you could imagine) but now i got it. thanks a lot